# Append rows to shapefile on disk (not in memory)?

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory, geopandas, chunking

I'm trying to combine [every block file from the 2010 census](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/TABBLOCK/) together into a single master block file for the US. I'm currently doing this in Google Colab and even on their pro subscription - which gives you about 25GB of RAM - I'm maxing out all available memory on the 45th file (I just have 5 more to go!). Code wise, I'm just building a list of dataframes that need to be `concat`ed together and ultimately written to disk:

```
gdfs = []
census_blocks_basepath = r'/content/drive/My Drive/Census/blocks/'
census_block_filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(census_blocks_basepath) if f.endswith('.shp')]
for index, block_filename in enumerate(census_block_filenames):
  file_name = os.path.join(census_blocks_basepath, block_filename)
  gdfs.append(gpd.read_file(file_name))
  print('Appended file %s, %s' % (index, block_filename))

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(gdfs, ignore_index=True), crs=dataframesList[0].crs)
# gdf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
gdf.head(3)
```

Instead, I think I should:

1. load a single geodataframe
2. append it to a master dataframe that exists on disk (rather than in memory like [csv.writer](https://gist.github.com/Nyahua/7db3056ce2ba6df9ec84dd362eabe686))
3. delete the loaded geodataframe from `1` (to avoid memory accrual)
4. then repeat `1`-`3` for all geodataframes remaining in the source directory

I don't see documentation on whether geopandas supports disk based appends.. it only seems able to overwrite previous files via [`GeoDataFrame.to_file`](https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file). That said, I see that geopandas has a `GeoDataFrame.to_postgis` method with a [`chunksize` argument](https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis), which makes me think that it's possible to append data onto a geofile on disk (or I'm wrong and that's just a feature of `postgis`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From MartinFleis](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1571#issuecomment-676495324)

> Yes, any file format which supports appending (and is supported by fiona) can be appended. You just have to specify mode="a".
>
> `df.to_file(filename, mode="a")`
>
> You can check if a mode is supported using
>
> ```
> import fiona
> fiona.supported_drivers
> ```
>
> This is the current result r-read, a-append, w-write.
>
> ```
> {'AeronavFAA': 'r',
>  'ARCGEN': 'r',
>  'BNA': 'raw',
>  'DXF': 'raw',
>  'CSV': 'raw',
>  'OpenFileGDB': 'r',
>  'ESRIJSON': 'r',
>  'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw',
>  'GeoJSON': 'rw',
>  'GeoJSONSeq': 'rw',
>  'GPKG': 'rw',
>  'GML': 'raw',
>  'GPX': 'raw',
>  'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw',
>  'Idrisi': 'r',
>  'MapInfo File': 'raw',
>  'DGN': 'raw',
>  'PCIDSK': 'r',
>  'S57': 'r',
>  'SEGY': 'r',
>  'SUA': 'r',
>  'TopoJSON': 'r'}
> ```